# Weibel Lemma 1.6.2.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, additive-categories

The following is (a part of) Lemma 1.6.2. from Weibel's *Homological Algebra*.$\newcommand{\C}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}\newcommand{\md}[1]{{\left\lvert #1 \right\lvert}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$

> Let $\C{C} \subset \C{A}$ be a full subcategory of an abelian category $\C{A}$.
> $\C{C}$ is additive $\Leftrightarrow$ $0 \in \C{C}$, and $\C{C}$ is closed under $\oplus$.

---

I am having difficulty with the $\Rightarrow$ direction.
First, here is what I interpret the right side to mean: $\C{C}$ contains a zero object of $\C{A}$. Furthermore, given two objects $A, B \in \C{C}$, $\C{C}$ contains a coproduct of $A$ and $B$. (Where this coproduct was their coproduct in $\C{A}$.)

The part about the zero object was easy to show. Indeed, since $\C{C}$ is additive, it has some zero object, say $0'$. We now have to show that $0'$ is also a zero object in $\C{A}$. This follows since $\C{C}$ is a full subcategory because we have
\begin{equation*} 
\md{\Hom_{\C{A}}(0', 0')} = \md{\Hom_{\C{C}}(0', 0')} = 1,
\end{equation*}
showing that $0'$ is a zero object in $\C{A}$ as well.

The same sort of trick does not seem to work for $\oplus$, though. I started with objects $A, B \in \C{C}$. Now, since $\C{C}$ is additive, the coproduct $A \oplus' B$ in $\C{C}$ exists. I believe that I need to show that this is in $\C{A}$ as well but I don't see how.

I believe that I really need to use abelian-ity of $\C{A}$ since otherwise this statement is not true. That is, just being full doesn't mean that a coproduct in the subcategory is also one in the larger category. (Consider the full subcategory of abelian groups within groups. The coproduct in the former isn't one in the latter.)

Comment: You don't need the full strength of $\mathcal{A}$ being abelian. The point is that these are not just coproducts, but *bi*products. Use both the product and coproduct property of the biproduct in $\mathcal{A}$ to get canonical morphisms between the biproduct in $\mathcal{A}$ and the one in $\mathcal{C}$ in both directions. Some slightly extensive, but not difficult, computations with the components will prove they're inverse.

Comment: @Thorgott: Ah, thank you. I had forgotten that. I don't expect an answer to work out the explicit details, so you could post that as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-trivial statement you need is that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a category admitting finite biproducts and $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$ is the inclusion of a subcategory admitting finite biproducts, then that inclusion preserves the finite biproducts. To prove this, take a collection of objects $X_1,\dots,X_n\in\mathcal{C}$ and denote the coproducts $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}X_n$ and $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}X_n$ respectively. These come with natural inclusion and projection morphisms, which, by the universal properties of $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}X_n$ as both product and coproduct, induce natural morphisms $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}X_n\rightarrow X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}X_n$ and $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{A}}X_n\rightarrow X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}X_n$. Using, again, the universal property and calculating the components of their composites using the respective inclusions/projections (here, one needs the compatibility of inclusions and projections in a biproduct), one confirms that these maps are in fact inverse. Since the calculation in particular demonstrates that the canonical projections correspond under these isomorphisms, this shows that $X_1\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}\dots\oplus_{\mathcal{C}}X_n$ is also a biproduct in $\mathcal{A}$, as desired. Note that this argument works in particular if $n=0$, which is the case of the zero object.